# AngularJS not binding promise to template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

**My service:**

---

**This was mistake 1 of 2 cause of my error:**

```
        getAll: function(url) {
         deferred.resolve($http({  <--- deferred.resolve should not have been here
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: true,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }                    
            }));
            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

**Should have been instead:**

```
        getAll: function (url) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: true,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
```

---

**My controller:**

**This was mistake 2 of 2 cause of my error:**

```
     // $scope.PassengerVehicles = crudSvc.getAll('/_json/PassengerVehicles.js');
     // should have been:
      crudSvc.getAll('/_json/PassengerVehicles.js').then(function (data) {
        $scope.PassengerVehicles = data;
    });
```

**My template:**

```
       <ul data-ng-repeat="passVeh in PassengerVehicles">
          <li>{{passVeh.itemId}}</li>
        </ul>
```

**Here is my plunker, which has been corrected:**

[AngularJS not binding promise to template](http://plnkr.co/edit/QJlkMjh0MkXSRJGk7oJV?p=preview)

**Than You Fourth!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `getAll()` function immediatly resolving and returning a promise to the controller. You need to allow the `getAll()` function to execute and deal with the promise when that resolves:

```
getAll: function(url) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: true,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }                    
            });
        },
```

and in the controller:

```
    crudSvc.getAll('/_json/PassengerVehicles.js').success(function (vehicles){
        $scope.PassengerVehicles = vehicles;
      });
```

The difference is that you are returning a promise that immediately resolves and returns another promise. You only need to resolve the http promise.

Comment: I changed the service to exactly yours. My controller method call looks exactly as yours, the console output is as it was before, I still am not binding to the template.

Comment: Did you change your controller to look like mine because it didn't before. Debug the service call to ensure its returning a promise and debug the controller to ensure that the "then" function is being called.

Comment: Made a slight change to the service function and it should resolve your issue. Re-check my answer and note that I now return `response.data` instead of `response`.

Comment: That did not do it either, did you see my plunker?

Comment: I did and apologize because im less familiar with using $http directly. Here is a working plunker and ive updated my answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/yo8KhzS1uxvJA0X2ju3X?p=preview

Comment: Where is the promise? Your app has no promise.

Comment: $http returns its own kind of promise that results in either `success` or `failure`. You can wrap it up in a `q` promise but you don't stand to gain anything from it. Here is a plunker that demonstrates that: http://plnkr.co/edit/jdUuJe6s9anfwtgToVRG?p=preview